# Multiple buttons use same segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, segue

I'm fairly new to swift so please take it easy on me. I'm trying to use two buttons to go back to the same View Controller. One button will have some logic in it and the other button will simply cancel the scene and go back. I would like to do this by using the same segue.

```
  @IBAction func reduceButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToViewController", sender: sender)
  }
  @IBAction func cancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToViewController", sender: sender)
  }

  // MARK: - Navigation
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "BackToViewController"{
      let firstScene = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
  firstScene.reducedString = reducedString
}
```

I am unsure if this is the correct way to do this or if I am doing it completely wrong. Neither of my buttons will work and I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that both of your segues are named properly? Take a look at this screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/09MxJ.png

Comment: The segue has the identifier BackToViewController.

Comment: How do you present the second view controller? Modally? Show (push)?

Comment: A segue is not bidirectional. You either have to `popViewController` or create another segue back to your first view controller.

Comment: I have two segues. One comes from the first scene to the second scene and the other segue goes back to the first scene from the second scene. the second scene has two buttons on it that are supposed to both trigger going back to the first scene.

Comment: If your segue that points back is a normal segue then this is wrong. You either need to use a button action that calls a one of the pop navigation controller methods, or an unwind segue. Having a back button do a normal segue causes it to create a new copy of the previous view controller and add that to the stack.

Comment: OK. Thank you! I still have a ton to learn it seems.